# Unable to set label for the right axis using MPChart library

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfDsG.png)I am drawing a bar graph using the MPCharts library in android. The labels in the right axis is not setting properly whereas the left axis works seamlessly

So far i have tried the below approach. Can anyone guide me what is wrong here
`private void initializeAndPopulateChart(BarChart mChart, JSONObject singleObject) {

```
    mChart.clear();

    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
    mChart.setSelected(true);

    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

    mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(true);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(true);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);

    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);


    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    //xAxis.setAxisLineWidth(.5f);

    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setAxisLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white_two));
    xAxis.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white));
    xAxis.setSpaceMin(5f);

    //this is for x labels to show only which is in list

    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);

    //to always show region header start from -1
    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(-0.5f);


    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    leftAxis.setEnabled(true);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    leftAxis.setSpaceBottom(0);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    leftAxis.disableAxisLineDashedLine();


    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    rightAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    rightAxis.setEnabled(true);
    rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0);
    rightAxis.setSpaceBottom(0);
    rightAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    rightAxis.disableAxisLineDashedLine();

    setBarData(mChart, singleObject);
}
```

`